# Chartjs backgroundColor for line chart does not appear in Vue app

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to render a background (gradient, but simple color also doesn't work) for a line chart using chart.js 3.6.0 in a Vue 3 app. Users can toggle between a bar chart and a line chart (for the same dataset). Interestingly it works for the bar chart:

[image]

But the line chart has no gradient:

[image]

This is the data configuration:

```
data: {
    labels: props.labels as string[],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: props.data as number[],
            backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(), // returns the gradient
            borderColor: getBorderColor(), // returns a color
            fill: true // tried all possible values for this
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to remove everything that might cause an issue, but even the most basic configuration with hard-coded data doesn't work.

The canvas is accessed using a ref:

```
<template>
    <canvas class="statistics-canvas" ref="canvas" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    // ...
    setup() {
        const canvas = ref(document.createElement("canvas"));
        let chart: Chart;

        onMounted(() => createChart());

        function createChart() {
            chart = new Chart(canvas.value, {/*...*/});
        }

        return {
            canvas
        };
    }
</script>
```

Any ideas about what might be causing this? I have also tried coping the configuration from the chartjs docs (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html), but also no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please check the registrar file for chart js in your project. Add **Filler** to **Chart.register()**

```
import {
  ...,
  Filler,
} from 'chart.js';

Chart.register(
...,
Filler,
);
```

Comment: More info at: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#bundle-optimization under "Available plugins" and on Github at: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/tree/master/src/plugins/plugin.filler